# Kotlin - running an integration test, error `fun main is already defined`

Tags: maven, spring-boot, integration-testing, kotlin

I have written an integration test for a Web application but I don't know how to run this test. Maven build fails with the following error when I execute `mvn test`

```
[INFO] Compiling Kotlin sources from [src/main/kotlin]
[INFO] Classpath: <...>
[INFO] Classes directory is <...>\target\classes
[INFO] Module name is demo
[ERROR] <...>\src\main\kotlin\demo\Application.kt: (9, 1) 'public fun main(args: kotlin.Array<kotlin.String>): kotlin.Unit' is already defined in demo
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my main class (Application.kt)

```
package demo

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication

@SpringBootApplication
open class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java, *args)
}
```

Here is a part of my test class

```
package demo

import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.test.WebIntegrationTest
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner
import demo.Application
import demo.model.City
import demo.repository.CityRepository

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebIntegrationTest({"server.port=8080"})
class CityControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private var cityRepository: CityRepository?
    private val restTemplate: RestTemplate = TestRestTemplate()
    // ...
}
```

There is no such error when I execute `mvn clean test`. So I suppose Kotlin is frightened of previously compiled classes. Though I am very unsure...

What is the right way to run an integration test?

Comment: I've just found that [maven kotlin plugin does not support incremental build](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2014/10/m9-is-here/#comment-26342)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10051). Already fixed and the fix will be delivered very soon

Comment: I'm still experiencing something very similar to this bug. Which version should have the fix? I'm using `kotlin-plugin-1.0.0-beta-1038-IJ143-19` I think.